# Rails Integration Testing - How to Simulate bad CSRF token and Expired Session

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing, csrf

I just changed exception handling code in my application_controller.rb to correctly capture `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`.

I was previously doing a `rescue_from Exception` that was defined after the recuse_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken.  This was taking priority and my intended rescue_from code was not being executed.

I'd like to write an integration test to verify this behavior.  How can I create an object that will allow me to send a bad CSRF token to a post request to simulate this behavior?

I'd also like to have an object that will allow me to simulate an expired session to make a get request.  How would I implement these integration tests?

Comment: You can simply stub `verified_request?` to return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bad CSRF token can be simulated with:

```
with_forgery_protection do
    post user_session_path, {:authenticity_token => 'foo'}
    assert redirected_to_new_user_session_path
end
```

An expired session can be simulated using the TimeCop gem:

```
Timecop.travel 2.days.from.now do
    get some_authorized_path
    assert_redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```