# How to test redirect when ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I have a rescue_from ***ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, with: :invalid_token*** in my ApplicationController.

the ***invalid_token*** redirects the user to nice view with a more clear message to the end user.

I have tried to write a test that simulates a session expiration with help of Timecop gem but im not getting it to work.

I have tried this solution to simulate a expired session
[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531101/rails-integration-testing-how-to-simulate-bad-csrf-token-and-expired-session?rq=1)

```
      user = create(:user, :with_company)

      visit new_user_session_path

      within "#sign_in_form" do
        fill_in :user_email, with: user.email
        fill_in :user_password, with: user.password

        click_button I18n.t("devise.sessions.new.sign_in")
      end

      assert page.has_link?(I18n.t("navbar.sign_out"))

      assert_current_path "/"

      # new_date = Time.zone.now + 1.month
      click_link I18n.t("breadcrumbs.orders")

      click_link I18n.t("orders.index.new_door")

      Timecop.travel 5.days.ago do  #session dosent get expired
        click_link I18n.t("pdf_button.title")
        assert_redirect_to "/invalid_token" #this brokes, it says it expects another path
      end
    end
```

Im trying to simulate a expired session with Timecop gem in my test to trigger InvalidAuthenticityToken so i can see that me redirect works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to change the auth token on the site to invalidate it (I think you can execute custom javascript within capybara to modify the auth_token on the form's hidden field and on the header meta tag) instead of moving the current datetime with Timecop.

Comment: Thank you, i will try that and give some feedback on how i did

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a time from_now, as they used in the example?

Something like this:
Timecop.travel 5.days.from_now

Comment: maybe the session isn't being affected, only the code inside the block, you could try to recreate the session with the modified time, or even initialize it with an expired time.

Comment: How do i recreate the session with an expired time in the test?

Comment: Unfortunally this didint work, i ended up mocking the exception i my test case instead of using Timecop or reset_session